# solr: import from different datasources using DIH

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, dih

I am trying to fill a Solr index from 2 different data-sources (xml and db) using the DataImportHandler.

1st try: Created 2 data-config.xml files, one for the xml import and one for the db import. 
The db-config would read `id` and lets say field `A`. The xml-config also `id` and field `B`.

That works for both (i could import from both datasources), but the index got overwritten each time (with `clean=false` of course), so I either had `id` and `A` or `id` and `B`

so on for the
2nd try: merged the 2 files into one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource 
        name="cr-db"
        jndiName="xyz"
        type="JdbcDataSource" />
    <dataSource 
        name="cr-xml" 
        type="FileDataSource" 
        encoding="utf-8" />


    <document name="doc">
        <entity 
            dataSource="cr-xml" 
            name="f" 
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor" 
            baseDir="/path/to/xml" 
            filename="*.xml" 
            recursive="true" 
            rootEntity="false" 
            onError="skip">
            <entity
                name="xml-data" 
                dataSource="cr-xml" 
                processor="XPathEntityProcessor" 
                forEach="/root" 
                url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" 
                transformer="DateFormatTransformer" 
                onError="skip">
                <field column="id" xpath="/root/id" /> 

                <field column="A" xpath="/root/a" />
            </entity>

            <entity 
                name="db-data" 
                dataSource="cr-db"
                query="
                    SELECT  
                        id, b
                    FROM 
                        a_table
                    WHERE 
                        id = '${f.file}'">
                <field column="B" name="b" />
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

A bit funny is the `id = '${f.file}'`-part i guess, but that is the id that is used. The select statement is correctly formed, but I get an exception when trying to run that file in the `dataimport.jsp`. The first part (xml) works fine, but when he gets to the db part it raises:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not find file: SELECT id, b FROM a_table WHERE id = '12345678.xml'
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.FileDataSource.getFile[..]
```

Any advice? Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT**
I found the problem for the FileNotFoundException: within the entity tags the `datasource`-attributes need to be camelCased --> `dataSource`..
Now it runs through, but with the same outcome as in the first try: only field `B` gets in the index. If I take the db-entity out, then the file contents are indexed (field `A`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<entity name="db-data" dataSource="cr-db"
```

The attributes are case-sensitive, so your wrong-cased attribute name is ignored and you fall back to the default one (which somehow is the file one).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just learned that too  :) However, I am back to the first problem, that only contents from the last datasource get into the index..

Comment: I am not sure of the level of support of having two inner Root entities. If you don't have too many XML files, I would just duplicate the outer entry definition and have each one with only one inner rootEntity=true entity. Though, you may need to worry about preImportDeleteQuery to make sure the entities do not delete each other's content. Oh, and when you are doing full DIH import (not delta), I believe the clear command runs automatically. Unless you explicitly override it.

Comment: Thanks again! the rooTEntity=true did the job. When I changed that at the FileListEntityProcessor everything worked as expected.